# What object is a Milestone-in-Entitlement-Process?

Tags: entitlements

API name of Entitlement Process is SlaProcess.
API name of Milestones is MilestoneType.
API name of Milestones applied to cases is CaseMilestone.

An Entitlement Process consists of milestones. But MilestoneType is merely the template for the milestones added to an Entitlement Process; when you add a Milestone to an EP, you specify additional attributes such as Minutes to Complete Milestone.

Adding milestones to EPs through the UI is time-consuming so I'd like to be able to mass create milestones-in-entitlement-processes. But it's not clear what that object is called or whether it's exposed through the API. Oddly, SlaProcess and related objects are absent from [the ERD](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_support.htm?search_text=restresource)

What object is a milestone added to an entitlement process, and can it be written from the API?

[image: What object is this?]

Comment: the object prefix for this object you are referring to is 553.. but i cdn't find anything related to it (tried looking in metadata types & standard objects using workbench)..

Answer (score 1):

This object NAme is MilestoneType

Comment: @Ratan This appears to be a valid answer. There is a [MilestoneType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_milestonetype.htm).

Answer (score 0):

A helpful support agent at SFDC tells me that the item in question is

**EntitlementProcessMilestoneItem**

and this is documented in the Metadata API [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_entitlementprocess.htm) along with the attributes of the EntitlementProcess metadata, which represents the attributes of the SlaProcess object.

He claims I should be able to insert EntitlementProcessMilestoneItems using the Metadata API but I have not yet attempted this.

Answer (score 0):

There are two Object 
1. MilestoneType 
2.CaseMilestone

The object which you are reffering is Casemilestone and it's parent is MilestoneType.

Comment: @TusharSharma This appears to be a valid answer. There is a [MilestoneType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_milestonetype.htm).

Comment: @crmprogdev yes but this user already posted same answer so thats why I flag this. Please correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: @TusharSharma I don't know which one was posted first. I agree that posts shouldn't be duplicated. The reasons cited for removing it weren't the proper reasons in which case a comment should have been made asking the user not to post the same answer twice, then flagging it for moderator intervention instead.

Comment: @Bhupendra can you please delete one of your answer because they both are duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The object is called Milestone. It is inaccesible via API for some reason. If you hover over the link and get the record id, it will begin with 553. Then in anonymous execute do the following where 553xxx is your record id.

Id sampleid = '553xxx'; System.debug('object is '+ sampleid.getsobjecttype());

This will return: object is Milestone. Hope this helps someone as took me a while to figure out. I'd really like to know why this object can only be interacted with via the UI. It's causing a lot of problems for me in the MilestoneTriggerTimeCalculator Interface where I want to be able to create time trigger based in part on the Milestone Business hours